# I am looking for a resource that finds words with a certain root in Tanakh

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, grammar-dikduk, aleph-bet-letters

I am a beginner in Hebrew and so please forgive me if my question shows profound ignorance.

I would like to pull up or list verses in the Tanakh based on them having a particular vocabulary word in it.   So if I am memorizing the word ראש, it should include Bereshit 1:1 because of בְּרֵאשִׁית.

I want to read the word I am interested in in various contexts.

Is there such of a resource either in either book or electronic form?  I am not interested in Christian sources such as Strong's Concordance which are based on the English translation.

Comment: The Even Shoshan Concordance might be worth a look.

Comment: An additional resource for you might be [אמרי מדריך (_Imrei Madrich_)](http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=4339), a _Chumash_, which highlights the _shoresh_ (root) within every word in the Torah.

Comment: @ezra I looked at a sample page. I'm not completely following its method. At any rate, I think this an answer to the OP's question, so why not post that along with a brief explanation of how their method works and why you recommend it.

Comment: I have purchased both the Even Shoshan and the Imrei Madrich.   The Imrei looks to be an excellent resource as well to identify the Shoresh.  Thank you both for your suggestions.

Comment: @ezra Do you know of a resource that does the same as the Imrei Madrich for the entire Tanakh?

Comment: Thank you for the awesome question. This is something I've been looking for as well.

Comment: @WestonKohn - I do not, although the title page of the Imrei Madrich says "al chamisha chumshei torah" and "yehoshua - yeshayah" on it, so maybe it also contains Yehoshua through Yeshayah.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84061

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to an electronic source that gives you the roots that is based off Imrei Madrich and other various sources. [App with Hebrew Roots](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.LnDGen)

Comment: I got scared for a minute. I thought this was related to the Hebrew Roots Movement there for a second, but then I realized what they were really talking about... :P

Comment: Thank you for the link.   I have downloaded stuff of Amazon thinking it Judaica and have found, upon using it, to be Messianic.   This does look good though.

Comment: Is there an iOS version?

Answer (score 2):

Sefaria has recently updated their search engine to do this. By default, “exact match” is turned off, so ראש will also match בראשית. Just make sure to filter it to just תנ״ך, and turn off the various תרגומים while you’re at it. It’s not perfect, though: the word קו, with some prefix or suffix, appears 16 times in Tanach, but their search engine returns just 10 of them.