# Is There an Online Concordance for Tanach from Religious Jewish Sources?

Tags: product-recommendation, tanach, internet

If you do a Search for an online CONCORDANCE for Tanach, chances are near certain you'll end up in a Christian site, which would be inappropriate, even if your search there can be successful. In fact, most such sites sport a non-denominational facade, so the searcher may well think he's on safe ground when in fact he thereby gives aid for trapping naive Jews who know next to nothing about their own religion. There are many Christian sites that set out a priori to hunt for and trap such innocent but clueless Jews. Is there a religious Jewish site (also as opposed to a "Reformist" brand) for searching Tanach we can rely on and explore comfortably, without otherwise abetting those who would will the Jew forsake his roots?

Comment: One such place I found is Hebrewbooks.org although it is a beast to handle, because it's main focus is not to be a concordance. Finding words in Tanach therein seems to be an afterthought they added to the site. And most times you'd end up rather empty-handed because of its clumsiness.

Comment: The Bar Ilan responsa site would do the trick I think but you need to register for it and I don't know if there are any parameters to registering.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83627

Comment: THE site for these searches is at HTTP://TORAWARE.COM, which focuses on words - not on books, as the source above. This site has 11 search methods, yields quick results and has powerful options for each method. You can set your range, eg all of Tanach, or just Torah, or one Chumash, Megillah, Tehillim etc. The database is the KSIV version of Tanach, as of now. Comments to the author, there, are appreciated and responded to as well. What's more, you can follow progress of that site's development at torawaredotcom.blogspot.com. The site is intuitive and user-friendly. Though as yet isn't mobile.

Comment: What’s wrong with a Christian concordance, if you limit your search to the so-called “Old” Testament?

Answer (score 0):

[Mechon-Mamre](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/search.htm) provides a search box which, when you type in a Hebrew word, comes up with all the sources in the Tanach that have the word.  I believe you can also do it with English too.

It's far from being exhaustive.

Comment: Please try http://toraware.com for comparison, both functionally and intuitively. For example, the site you mention (which I visit often, by the way), is geared for another main focus, to the extent that the site has a "site map" to help steer you, because of the complexity of the site. In contrast, toraware is strictly a search tool as well as an online concordance. The site's 3 pages (Methods;Options;Results) is a simple, useful and streamlined search "gadget".

Comment: Sefaria’s search engine works the same way, and recently they’ve added support for near-matches, so ראש will also return בראשית.

Comment: First of all, DonielF, so two search sites "work the same way". But after visiting Sefaria, I can tell you they work COMPLETELY DIFFERENTLY! They may, in the end, spit out the same results, but http://TORAWARE.COM in my humble opinion beats all torah-search engines I've ever visited (and I began in the days of machine language, and DOS) - hands down! As an example, the former lays out a whole page of Holy Books to choose from (and there are over 50), whereas a simple drop-down list accomplishes the same thing at http://TORAWARE.COM in one field on one line.

Comment: Another example, the former site has all sorts of Judaica, of which the search capability is secondary - where in toraware's site the whole thing is dedicated just to searches.